# Is there any idea of change in technology with the changing of yugas?

Tags: yuga

We see with the change of yugas different laws are changed or the general conduct of the people are changed etc., so does the same apply to the change of technology? Like maybe in Krita yuga they didn't know how to this but then in Kali yuga they now know how to do that thing etc.